# Using jQuery Ajax to deal with xml file

Tags: jquery, xml-parsing

I'm new to Ajax and Xml parsing with jQuery and i have a little problem with it. I wan't to retrieve datas from a non local xml file here : http://www.velib.paris.fr/service/carto/carto.xml . 
In Ajax, i coded this :

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET' ,
    url: 'http://www.velib.paris.fr/service/carto/carto.xml' ,      
    success: function(xml) {
        console.log('Success') ;
        console.log(xml) ;            
    } ,
    error: function() {
        console.log('Error') ;
    }
}) ;
```

But, the "console.log(xml) is returning a string with html tags in it. yet, it's clearly xml (by the extension, and when u go the page i mentionned above). Maybe i'm doing something wrong, so i need help, please :)

Answer (score 1):

Pass `dataType: "xml"` to the ajax call, so that jQuery can parse the response text as xml and pass the result to the success callback

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET' ,
    url: 'http://www.velib.paris.fr/service/carto/carto.xml' ,      
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(xml) {
        console.log('Success') ;
        console.log('Success found maker: ' + jQuery(xml).find('marker').length) ;
        console.log(xml) ;            
    } ,
    error: function() {
        console.log('Error') ;
    }
}) ;
```

Comment: The console log still return "Object {responseText: "<html>↵  <head>↵    <meta content="HTML Tidy for J…rator"/>↵    <title/>↵  </head>↵  <body/>↵</html>"}" .

Comment: no, it is a xml object which you can query like `console.log('Success found maker: ' + jQuery(xml).find('marker').length) ;`

Comment: copy and paste the above command in your console (with [http://www.velib.paris.fr/](http://www.velib.paris.fr/) opened), you will get _Success found maker: 1226_ printed in the console

Comment: By my side, it return : "Success found maker: 0". I also tried it in local. It works well and returns an xml formated which i can parse.

Comment: There could be a problem of [Same Origin Policy](http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy), if you are working on a local page and tries to access `http://www.velib.paris.fr/service/carto/carto.xml` the browser will not allow it. To access the above resource you need to be working on a page within `http://www.velib.paris.fr/` domain

Comment: What do you mean by "in the console" ? because i get an error : "xml is not defined"

Comment: Concerning the Same Origin Policy, i'm using a jquery plugin named "xdomainajax" form Cross Request